# PHP - Reading text from textfile creating nested <div>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Good morning everyone,

I am reading a textfile from our server which changes its content every 10 seconds. I am displaying it using this code:

```
<div id="textfile">
    <?php 
         $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']  . "/resources/file.txt";
         $content = file_get_contents($file);
         echo $content;
   ?>
</div>
```

I am using jquery in updating the content and displaying it.

```
setInterval(function() {
     $('#textfile').load(document.URL +  " #textfile");
}, 10000);
```

However if it is updated, it creates another < div >.
Previously it looks like this..

```
<div>Content</div>
```

But after it refreshes, it looks like this..

```
<div>
   <div> Content </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code and please help me so that it won't create another < div > after it refreshes..

Comment: What is inside `file.txt`? HTML ??

Comment: Try adding `$('#textfile').html('');` in the interval, before the load.

Comment: @Ayush inside the file.txt is just plain text.

Comment: @PHPglue all it did was blink.. but it did not remove the <div>

Answer (score 0):

You can load the text file directly, and reload it every 10 seconds.

```
<div id="textfile"></div>

<script src="path/to/the/jquery/lib.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            $('#textfile').load('path/to/the/text/file.txt');
        }, 10000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @Kenny i know that but i need it to refresh every 10 seconds and not refresh the whole page itself..

Comment: Of course you can do that by adding a setInterval function. (Check out my edited answer)

Comment: i was avoiding getting the file path in javascript. because it is causing some issues that i find it hard to trace. that is why i just did it in php. But thanks for your answer though.